# how to implement UI changes when resuming fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, fragment, onresume

i'm a beginner developing in kotlin * android studio. i have 2 fragments in my app: a main fragment and a settings fragment. the two share a viewmodel. heres what i'm trying to accomplish:

1. app launches, takes you to main fragment
2. user clicks settings button, takes you to settings fragment
3. user alters settings (preferences stored in shared viewmodel)
4. user returns to main fragment, UI of main fragment is altered based on which settings were selected

i have completed steps 1-3 and am trying to implement 4. i am thinking i should override onResume() in my main fragment and implement UI changes there. first off, is this a good idea? if so, how can i access my UI elements from onResume()? any guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe both of your fragments are living in the same activity in which case using a shared `ViewModel` is not a bad idea.

Having said that, for settings it might be a good idea to save them in `SharedPrefences` if they are primitive small sized data (String, int etc..)

You are right about overriding `onResume()` to change your UI. Since you are going to make those changes from your fragment you should override `onViewCreated()` and inside `onViewCreated()` you can access your UI elements like this, for example:

```
val textView = activity.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.my_textview)
```

Or, you can bind your `ViewModel` directly into your layout in that case you don't even have to override anything. You can read further about that [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding)

Comment: thanks! i was trying to avoid using "findVewById" bc in my training i was warned this is computationally expensive. but i guess within the onResume function there is no way to avoid this since databinding is not accessible from here?